# Checking consecutive positive values of a Numpy Array Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, indexing

How can I code a function that shows how many consecutive positive values there are starting from the end to the start of the arrays `A, B, C`. So array `B` has 2 positive consecutive values starting from the end `3,5` hence why resulting in the output of `2`.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([2,5,44,-12,3,-5])
B = np.array([2,5,44,-12,3,5])
C = np.array([2,5,44,12,3,5])
```

Expected output:

```
0
2
6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of the last negative value first, and then subtract it from the array length:

```
def count_trailing_positive(a):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(a < 0)        # find all indices of negative values
    if len(idx) > 0:
        return len(a) - idx[-1] - 1    # subtract last index from array length
    else:
        return len(a)

count_trailing_positive(A)
# 0
count_trailing_positive(B)
# 2
count_trailing_positive(C)
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def count_last_pos(arr):
    d = (arr>0)[::-1]
    return (d.cumsum() * d.cumprod()).max()

count_last_pos(A)
# 0 
count_last_pos(B)
# 2
count_last_pos(C)
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

The cumulative minimum over a positiveness mask of the reversed array:

```
def num_consec_pos_from_end(arr):
    return np.minimum.accumulate(arr[::-1] > 0).sum()
```

where the `arr[::-1] > 0` will give a boolean array and we need the number of `True`s until a `False`. Since `False` compares less than `True`, `minimum.accumulate` will change to `False` once and for all if it sees one. Then we sum the resultant array i.e., sum the `True` values for the output,

to get

```
>>> num_consec_pos_from_end(A)
0

>>> num_consec_pos_from_end(B)
2

>>> num_consec_pos_from_end(C)
6
```